# Does or will EntityFrameworkCore have SQL Server CE v4.0 support?

Tags: sql-server-ce, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working on migrating to .net core the EF against SQL Server CE v4.0, and now researching on its replacement.

Yet, I failed to find any, from here https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/sql-compact/index.html, the only named third-party provider still does not yet support .net core.

Does or will (soon) Entity Framework Core have SQL Server CE v4.0 provider supported other than this one?

Thanks, Elaine

Comment: The "best" replacement is SQLite (for better or worse)

Answer (score 2):

Sql Compact edition is in deprecation mode (no further development) and is not cross platform, so there is no chance of a .NET Core compatible provider for it. Microsoft are recommending SQLite as the cross-platform file-based embedded option instead and have produced a .NET Core provider for that.